# Customize coveo Omnibox Result List

Tags: coveo

I am Enabling Results Suggestions with the Coveo Searchbox. 
Followed the article https://docs.coveo.com/en/2806/coveo-for-sitecore-v4/result-suggestions  which is successful and I am able to see the suggestions in the list coming through.
 The problem is - omnibox results list displays title and excerpt like this 
 [image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8vtf.png]
, but I want to display only Title just like this one [image] 
My First question is - how can I display only title in the omnibox results list like the one in the above image(don't need excerpt or firstsentences to display) 
 My Second question is - I want to apply custom css to the suggestions list, how can I achieve that.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: I am Enabling Results Suggestions with the Coveo Searchbox.

Answer (score 0):

The Omnibox Result List component includes a result template. We can edit that template to only show the title for example, or to show additional content. And its regular CSS practices to update the styling